# eigenvector and operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator, and let $M$ be a nontrivial subspace of $V$ that is invariant under $T$.

> Prove that $M$ contains an eigenvector of $T$.

I just have no idea about it.

Comment: So by restriction, $T_{|M}:M\longrightarrow M$. The characteristic polynomial of the latter has a root, so...

Comment: you mean $T_{|M}$ has a root? and why?

Comment: @user81235: use an @ to call people. And $T_{|M}$ is just a new operator in a new smaller complex vector space. Down to this subspace, you don't have to restrict yourself any more, and so you can just check the polynomial and it has a solution because you're over $\mathbb C$. And all eigenvectors of $T_{|M}$ are also eigenvectors of $T$.

Comment: @Nick Kidman, why it has a solution when it is over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @user81235: That's just some [esoteric result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) I once heard. But some people use it sometimes.